# R: change port to connect with SFTP server

Tags: r, sftp, geturl

I have a connection with an ftp server with the following code:

```
url       <- "ftp://MyServer"
userpwd   <- "MyUser:MyPass"
filenames <- getURL(url, userpwd = userpwd, ftp.use.epsv = FALSE, dirlistonly = TRUE, port = 22) 
filen     <- "MyFile.csv"      
rawdata   <- getURL(paste(url, filen, sep = ""), userpwd = userpwd, crlf =  TRUE)
```

The file will be moved to an SFTP server, so I need to change the input. This new SFTP server is accessed via port 22 instead of the standard port 21. At the moment the connection fails with the following error

```
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
  Failed to connect to MyServer port 21: Connection refused
```

It takes the wrong port, but how do I tell R to choose port 22?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the SFTP protocol in the URL, so the line

```
url       <- "ftp://MyServer"
```

should become

```
url       <- "sftp://MyServer"
```

`getUrl` will then use the SSH port (22).